# Access a file in package

Tags: java, junit

I am using JUnit to do some automated tests on my application, the tests are in a folder called tests in my JUnit classes package.
As of now, I access the files using the following:

```
File file = new File(MyClass.class.getResource("../path/to/tests/" + name).toURI());
```

Is there a cleaner (and nicer) way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: where are you files and test classes in eclipse package/folder view ?

Comment: The class I instantiate is in a package and the files are in another one at the same level of hierarchy (that's where the test cases are). Then in a subfolder I have the test files I use with each test case.

Comment: I have

/data/MyClass.java
 and 
/junitTests/tests/

I need to access the tests/ folder from MyClass.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the classloader to load your test data, then you can't use `File`. A `File` instance represents a path in the file system. The class loads files from the file system, or from jar files, or from zip files, or from somewhere else. The class loader thus doesn't let you access files, but resources.

Use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/the/absolute/path.txt")` to load the contents, as an input stream, of the path.txt file. This file must be anywhere in the classpath: whether path.txt is in the file system or in a jar doesn't matter as soon as it can be found in the classpath, in the package `the.absolute`. So if your data files are in a tests folder, which is just under the sources directory of your tests, the path to use should be `/tests/data.txt`. Note that this works because Eclipse automatically "compiles" files which are not Java files by just copying them to the output directory (bin or classes, traditionally), and that this directory is in the classpath when you run your tests.

If you want to load this data as text rather than bytes, just wrap the `InputStream` with an `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

I make sure they're in the classpath, and then use

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("../path/to/tests/" + name);
```

I'm not sure it's much better, though.  What don't you like about what you use now?

This works because/when the resource file is in the classpath.  This is done for you for free when it's in the source path in Eclipse or Intellij.  If you're doing automated testing using Hudson or something like that, you'll need to make sure that your build process (Ant, Maven, shell script, whatever) puts them in the classpath as well.

Comment: the `..` doesn't work, see the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String). But as you said, using a fully qualified path, the tests are still more self-contained and predictable than referencing some file in the file system.

Comment: I am not a really experienced Java programmer but I thought that way to access files within the package was.. "dirty"..

Comment: @Dilum - I don't know what you read, or what you thought I meant, but it works for me, and I don't see what you're referring to in the docs.  To clarify: the example I gave will find the subpackage path.to.tests of the parent package of the package that the current class is in.  So, for instance, if MyClass is in package com.foo.bar, this will locate "name" in com.foo.path.to.tests.  Of course, since this is a class path, it may be in an entirely different file-system hierarchy than the test class - or not - depending on your needs.

Comment: @Luke, for getting resources for test inputs, it's generally easier and more flexible to use the class system, not the filesystem, to reference them.  Of course, you may NEED to test filesystem behavior, so ignore this if so.  For resources other than test resources, like config files and the like, you need to ensure that you give yourself enough flexibility for the situation.  For example, if you're doing integration testing where you need to refer to external resources via a config file, you'll probably want to add a level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is using of the method getFile() from URL, like so:

```
File file = new File(MyClass.class.getResource("../path/to/tests/" + name).getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data would fit more inside your /tests/ folder. It would avoid you to use a relative path starting from MyClass and would be more logical. Also, you could give my class a file paramater to load the data file. It would then be called both with production data and with tests data.

Regards,
 Stéphane